# Android-Complex Query in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple Database structure, I want to do a query on it :
get the article wherein motcle contains.(key), and from the articles found we order them by the highest `note`. 
I know that to do the "AND" I have to make a nested query. but how can I get the first node the `article` when I am in the second node `motcle`.
the Database

[image: here is my Database]

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider changing the way data is structured, e.g. storing "html" is your case as value istead of key? (or migrate to Firestore, which provides better querying capabilities)

Then you could do query similar to

```
ref("article").child(id)
    .orderByChild("motocle/someKey")
    .equalTo("Html")
```

This is typical approach with Firebase, when data is structured based on query you need.

Comment: I can't change the structure because I can have more words like "HTML", they are tags like the ones in StackOverflow, and for switching to Firestore I used realtime database for a long time can't change it now (deadline in a week) so there is no direct solution to it ?

Comment: Quick and dirty solution is to query all articles and filter/sort on client side :)

Comment: You could store multiple tags with substructures: `tagName="html", count=3`

Comment: if I use `snapshot.ref();` won't I have the Article?